# Changing symbology of a single selected polygon feature instead of the entire feature class value

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, symbology, editing, select-by-attribute

Using ArcGIS 10.7

I am editing a polygon layer, which I set to transparent so that I can make my edits according to a raster template underneath. With the amount of edits I am doing I would like to keep track of the edits by color filling the edited polygons features.

I have tried keeping the edited polygon selected and then going to layer properties > symbology, and changing the symbol properties for the class value the polygon belongs to. However, this changes the symbology for all polygon features belonging to the class, instead of just the selected feature (I get the same result when I select 'Properties for selected symbols'). Basically, I would like to know if there is a quick way to color fill the single feature polygon I select in order to keep track of edits.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Try to make ddp from polygons. Clone layer and set if definition query to match ddp page name.

Answer (score 1):

While you have the feature selected, right-click the layer in the table of contents, click Selection, then Create Layer From Selected Features. ArcGIS will create a new layer containing only that feature, and it will be set as a randomly-colored filled polygon by default.

[image]

You could also turn on [editor tracking](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-fundamentals/about-tracking-an-editor-s-changes-to-data.htm) on your dataset. Then you could symbolize the layer so that any feature with your name as the editor is a filled polygon.

Comment: I've considered this but it isn't practical for the editing process. I don't want to keep creating additional layers of edited and selected features. Rather, it would be so much easier to be able to simply change symbology of a single part feature in the existing layer and continue to edit through. It seems like there must be a built in way to keep track of existing edits in a similar fashion as I've suggested.

Comment: @kent There is, your data needs to have [editor tracking](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-fundamentals/about-tracking-an-editor-s-changes-to-data.htm) enabled. Then you could symbolize the layer so that any feature with your name as the editor is a filled polygon.

Comment: That is a good suggestion. I am able to fill the edited polygons this way. Thanks.